# Order total is cut off on checkout page of site built with Wix

Tags: wix

I am currently building a website through my WIX account (e-commerce site in particular), and there is a cart page where the number field is partly not showing attached in the screenshot below:

[image]

As you see in the screenshot, on the cart order page (which I cropped out the orders), the order summary price values are cut off the zeroes. I do not know how to make it so that the zeros do not get cut out, I tried to go to cart page settings and change the fonts etc, but I just cannot seem to see anything that allows me to get the whole numerical value to show.

I would appreciate any help offered thank you.

Comment: I would not recommend Wix because they lock you in.  It is desirable to be able to choose your hosting company based on best price and services.  [Once you have built a site on Wix, you can't export it and move it elsewhere](https://support.wix.com/en/article/exporting-or-embedding-your-wix-site-elsewhere).   Rather than figure out how to get this particular feature to work on Wix, build your site somewhere else instead using tools that can be migrated from one hosting company to another.

Comment: Could you possibly recommend me some other sites? Personally speaking it is just gonna be a website where i just need to see the orders of my customers once they make a payment. I do not think it will matter too much no?

Comment: A very popular option to create an eCommerce site would be to use WordPress with WooCommerce.   There are thousands of hosts that can handle that setup.